# ReplyOverflow v1.0

Tags: script

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

ReplyOverflow preserves continuity between comments everytime you reply by allowing an option to save the message content to a URL.

#### How do I use it?

If you want to reply to a comment, click the 'reply' button on the right of the comment, like so:

[image: StackReplies-Demo3]

When you click on the button, you'll automatically be directed towards the comment textarea with a link in the front:

[image]

Simply type the contents of your message after that jumbled mess, and press 'Add comment.' The result should look like this (if you typed 'nice'):

[image]

At this point, the content of the message has been saved. To retrieve it, press **Control + Shift + F**, and paste the generated URL into the prompt:

[image: StackReplies-Demo4]

---

<sup>Disclaimer: ReplyOverflow does not guarantee that the preserved content is reliable. Due to the nature of ReplyOverflow which gives the user full control over what they are doing, the link can be modified such that the URL parser's final result is different from the original comment. **Should only be used for continuity, not as evidence or for justification purposes**.</sup>

#### License

ReplyOverflow is licensed under the MIT License

#### Download

Minified userscript can be found here: https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/blob/main/scripts/reply-overflow/v1/script.min.user.js

#### Platform

Should support on all browsers that support JavaScript

### Contact

[Spectric](https://stackapps.com/users/76056/spectric)

### Code

Languages:

- JavaScript

Libraries:

- CryptoJS

Comment: I do not know if this is a bug or not but actually I noticed if I have written a message like "Hello" then I clicked on 'reply' button, so it removes all content of the message and I need to retype "Hello" again. As I am JS developer I think it is from `.innerHTML` which it removes all other content as well.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour Yep. That's a good idea - I'll add support for content already typed into the textarea.